# How To Unclamp B-Splines Curves

Tags: python, math, geometry, spline

I would like to convert a clamped non-rational cubic B-spline into an unclamped non-rational B-spline. (Note: both sides may be clamped or just one). How does one update the knots and controlpoints such that the splines are the same? (i.e. get same spline that no longer interpolates endpoints)

I currently have tried implementing Piegl and Tiller's Algorithm A12.1 "UnclampCurve" in The Nurbs Book (p.577). I am using the splipy package for evaluating my splines. My results are close but not the same!

```py
# using cubic splines
k = 4  # order
p = k - 1 # degree

# Create a clamped curve
cpts1 = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 4], [-4, 3, 5], [4, 3, -2]])  # control points
k1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1 / 3, 2 / 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])  # knot vector
basis1 = splipy.BSplineBasis(k, k1)
curve1 = splipy.Curve(basis1, cpts1)

# Unclamped version
n = len(cpts1) - 1
u = k1.copy()  # knot vector for unclamped curve
new_cpts = cpts1.copy() # controlpoints for unclamped curve

# unclamp left
for i in range(0, p - 1):
    u[p - i - 1] = u[p - i] - (u[n - i + 1] - u[n - i])
    k = p - 1
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        alfa = (u[p] - u[k]) / (u[p + j + 1] - u[k])
        new_cpts[j] = (new_cpts[j] - alfa * new_cpts[j + 1]) / (1 - alfa)
        k -= 1
u[0] = u[1] - (u[n - p + 2] - u[n - p + 1]) # set first knot

# unclamp right
for i in range(0, p - 1):
    u[n + i + 2] = u[n + i + 1] + (u[p + i + 1] - u[p + i])
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        alfa = (u[n + 1] - u[n - j]) / (u[n - j + i + 2] - u[n - j])
        new_cpts[n - j] = (new_cpts[n - j] - (1 - alfa) * new_cpts[n - j - 1]) / alfa
u[n + p + 1] = u[n + p] + (u[2 * p] - u[2 * p - 1]) # set last knot

# create unclamped bspline from above calculated knots, u, and controlpoints, new_cpts
basis2 = splipy.BSplineBasis(k, u)
curve2 = splipy.Curve(basis2, new_cpts)

# compare values
t1 = np.linspace(curve1.start(0), curve1.end(0), 1000)
t2 = np.linspace(curve2.start(0), curve2.end(0), 1000)
print(np.allclose(curve1.evaluate(t1), curve2.evaluate(t2))) # printing False, see visualization below
```

Current output visualized:

[image]